# innerHTML not working properly when used on a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/amrita2/zg4903q0/) code isn't working as expected. It is not showing any text inside of span.day where it should be showing today's day (Tuesday at the time of writing). It is also not properly adding the class "currentDay" inside of the `$.each` callback.

```
 $('#showLess span.day').innerHTML=weekday[today]; 

 $.each($('#showMore p span.day'), function(index, item) {  
      if(typeof item.innerHTML != 'undefined') 
      {     
           alert('item.text:' +item.innerHTML);
           alert('weekday[today]'+item.innerHTML.indexOf(weekday[today])); 

           if(item.innerHTML.indexOf(weekday[today])!=-1) { 
                alert("check which element has added class currentDay:");
                item.addClass('currentDay');
           }else{
                if(item.hasClass('currentDay')) {
                     item.removeClass('currentDay'); 
                }
           }
      } 
 });
```

`.innerHTML` is not changing the HTML, additional class is not getting added as expected.

```
<p id="showLess" class="less">
        <span class="day">**Tuesday**</span>
</p>
```

Why isn't the day showing?

Why is the show/hide not working?

```
$('.less').on('click', function(e) {
            $('#showMore').show();
            $('#showLess').hide();
        });

        $('.more').bind('click', function(e) {
            $('#showLess').show();
            $('#showMore').hide();
        });
```

Comment: the fiddle's nice, but post the code here.

Comment: @Amy I would check out: https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to invoke JS properties on jQuery objects.

For example `innerHTML`

And you are trying to invoke that on a jQuery object.

```
$('#showLessHours span.day').innerHTML
```

Should be

```
$('#showLessHours span.day')[0].innerHTML
```

**or**

```
$('#showLessHours span.day').html(weekday[today]);
```

And in your `each loop` **item** is a JS object and you are trying to add a class using jQuery. Convert that to jQuery object first .

```
item.addClass('currentDay');
item.removeClass('currentDay');
```

should be

```
$(item).addClass('currentDay');  or $(this).addClass('currentDay');
$(item).removeClass('currentDay'); or $(this).removeClass('currentDay')
```

Instead you can use the `$(this)` as well instead of `$(item)` object inside the callback as both refer to the same objects.

Another small suggestion is why do you want to mix vanilla JS and jQuery when jQuery is included and you want to use that in your application.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/8wLwwhw7/3/)**

Comment: Why does the `p` has both `<p id="showLessHours" class="hours-less"> <span class="day"></span>
 <span class="opHours"></span>
 <a href="#" class="hours-more"> (show)</a>

</p>` show-less and show-more classes. It would trigger both the events.

Comment: For some reason, this is still not working for me. I copied the code as is, it works in Fiddle/seperate page, but not when I try adding it to a Factory/Service in Angular.js...

Comment: should I be placing this in the document.onReady or window.onLoad

Answer (score 1):

Because .innerHTML isn't a jquery function.  You can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to achieve what you are trying to do.  Alternatively, if you REALLY want to use .innerHTML, you can use [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to get the actual DOM element, and *then* use .innerHTML but... I wouldn't recommend it.

I believe [this edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wLwwhw7/1/) solves your problem.  Relevant code:

```
$('#showLessHours span.day').html(weekday[today]);
//...
if(item.html() != '') {     
    alert('item.text:' +item.text());
    alert('weekday[today]'+item.text().indexOf(weekday[today]));
    if(item.html().indexOf(weekday[today])!=-1) {
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Sushanth said, you are also trying to invoke jQuery methods on javascript objects.

```
item.addClass
```

should by

```
$(item).addClass
```